# How to output a map in a template in Go syntax?

Tags: go, templates

for example, in go I have `x := map[string]bool{"1":true,"2":true}`
How can I print it to go.tmpl, using the built-in template package?

```
// go.tmpl
{{x}}
```

after render, I want it to be like

```
x := map[string]bool{"1":true,"2":true}
```

Do I have some approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
s := `{{x}}`
x := map[string]bool{"1": true, "2": true}
t, err := template.New("t").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "x": func() string { return fmt.Sprintf("x := %#v", x) },
}).Parse(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Pww7-PFIWXJ